# php 5.5.36 -> if/else format no longer working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I upgraded from PHP Version: 5.2.17 (Zend: 2.2.0) TO  5.5.36 (Zend: 2.5.0).

My third party script (CMS) has hundreds of T_VARIABLE errors because this syntax is no longer working:

```
if ($x $x == 1) {
//do
}
```

Obviously it should be:

```
if ($x && $x == 1) {
//do
}
```

My question is ... when was the latter format acceptable? What version was this even allowed?

Looked through PHP release notes to no avail.

Thank you.

Comment: anyone know regex (find&replace) that could highlight all these types of errors?

Comment: First one looks like it should be a parse error in any PHP version. Second one will always be true.

Comment: Any PHP IDE, or a text editor with the right plugin will highlight the errors without you needing to figure out a regex for them.

Comment: somehow, it was working on my old box though? no errors. i am moving away from the cms, but I want to have a legacy version available during transition ... need it working. ty!!

Comment: using notepadd++, plugin suggestion?

Comment: cli linter, `php -l script.php`

Comment: It surprises me that it used to work. I'm not saying you're wrong; there's still plenty of stuff I don't know, but it is surprising. Check this: https://3v4l.org/SCIkL Not sure about a npp plugin. I'm using sublime text w/ sublime linter package (which does use `php -l` behind the scenes if I remember correctly.)

Comment: was just as surprised as you that it was working, which is why i started digging into php 4 release notes, came up empty, then came here ;) thanks for your time!